# Using global hook to capture IME message

Tags: c++, vsto, hook

I am currently developing a VSTO Word Add-In program. And I have to capture IME messages to monitor the input status. There are two message I am trying to capture here:

1,IMC_OPENSTATUSWINDOW(when the candidate bar is openning) 2,IMC_CLOSESTATUSWINDOW(when the candidate bar is closing).

Below is the code I am using. It works fine in basically any Apps(like winform, wpf, or notepad++, because I am using a global hook here), however, when I use this code in Vsto Word Add-in apps, IMC_CLOSESTATUSWINDOW message can never be captured. Anyone has any ideas or any clue will be appreciated.

```
int CandidateBarOpen = 0;
LRESULT CALLBACK HookshurufaProcess(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
  //win10
  PMSG pmsg = (PMSG)lParam;
  if (pmsg->message == WM_IME_NOTIFY){
    if (pmsg->wParam& IMC_CLOSESTATUSWINDOW){
        CandidateBarOpen = 1;
    }
    else if (pmsg->wParam& IMC_OPENSTATUSWINDOW){
        CandidateBarOpen = 0;
    }
  }
  return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for noticing, just edited to c++.

Answer (score 0):

The Microsoft docs is clear about this (  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374139(v=vs.85).aspx ). You should use the`IMN_OPENSTATUSWINDOW` and `IMN_CLOSESTATUSWINDOW` parameters with `WM_IME_NOTIFY`, not `IMC_OPENSTATUSWINDOW` and `IMC_CLOSESTATUSWINDOW`.

The last two commands should be used with `WM_IME_CONTROL`.

Comment: Thanks for reply, and I have tried IMN_OPENSTATUSWINDOW and IMN_CLOSESTATUSWINDOW, these two message can be triggered by some input methods, but, for thoes input methods developed in recent years, these message is abandoned, because there is a new mechanism for developing input methods since windows 10. And I am sure IMC_OPENSTATUSWINDOW and IMC_CLOSESTATUSWINDOW is the messages I am looking for. The only problem is, these two can't be captured in Vsto Word Add-in, it works fine with other apps.